# How to convert time from English to French format using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, datetime

I want to convert this:

```
04/01/2021 02:06:22 PM
```

to:

```
04/01/2021 14:06:22
```

I tried many things but not success, thank you for your help

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: according to his edit he's tried many things lol

Comment: jonrsharpe you like to comment

Comment: There are many, many questions on [reformatting date strings](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+reformat+date). Read a few, write some code, post another question if you have issues.

Comment: @RobG you are right! Comment deleted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
date.toLocaleString("fr");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `toLocaleString()` method to change time formatting to 24 hours, e.g. `date.toLocaleString('en-US', {hour12: false})`. The `toLocaleString` method returns a string that represents the date and time according to the provided locale and options parameters.

```js
const date = new Date();

console.log(
  date.toLocaleString('en-US', {
    hour12: false,
  }),
);
```